# Python matplotlib.pyplot from SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am new to SQL and I want to create a bar chart based on my SQL query. I am using the SAKILA database. I got the following query and output:

Sakila database: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT rating, COUNT(film_id)
FROM film
GROUP BY rating;
```

**Output:**

| rating | COUNT(film_id) |
| --- | --- |
| PG | 194 |
| G | 178 |
| NC-17 | 210 |
| PG-13 | 223 |
| R | 195 |

Is there a way to create a bar chart using Python's matplotlib.pyplot with each bar correlating to a rating and its count (e.g. x-axis rating and y-axis COUNT(film_id))? I tried the following, but it is not executing:

```
plt.bar(df["number_of_films"])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

strc = {"rating": ["PG", "G", "NC-17", "PG-13", "R"], "COUNT(film_id)": [194, 178, 210, 223, 195]}

df = pd.DataFrame(strc)

ax = df.plot.bar(x='rating', y='COUNT(film_id)', rot=0)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

You will get the figure:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it a different way where it updates automatically based on the result from the query? For ex, what if the value for PG changes from 194 to 150?